# How to show QWindow inside QMdiArea

Tags: qt, opengl, qt5, shader

I have a OpenGLWindow class that inherits QWindow and QOpenGLFunctions_3_3_Core, it's opening collada dae files (works fine in simple project).

Also i have a pdfViewer class that inherits  from QWidgets.

I want to display this windows in MdiArea class:

```
void MainViewer::CreateSubWindow(QString &pathToFile)
{
    if (pathToFile.endsWith(".pdf"))
    {
        PdfViewer *newViewer=new PdfViewer(&pathToFile);
        m_LoadedFiles->insert(pathToFile,newViewer);//this qhash save inform of current opened docs, i need it
        m_MainMdiArea->addSubWindow(static_cast<PdfViewer*>(m_LoadedFiles->value(pathToFile)))->show();
    }
    if (pathToFile.endsWith(".dae"))
    {
        DaeViewer *newViewer=new DaeViewer(pathToFile);
        m_LoadedFiles->insert(pathToFile, newViewer);
        m_MainMdiArea->addSubWindow(m_LoadedFiles->value(pathToFile))->show();
        static_cast<DaeViewer*>(m_LoadedFiles->value(pathToFile))->OpenGLWindow::show();
        newViewer->setAnimating(true);
    }
    mdiSubWindowsCount++;
}
```

Getting the same result:

[image]

I understood that show method of QWidget and QWindow is different.

I want to see my openGlWindow in myMdiArea but don't know how to call show method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

[image]

```
DaeViewer *newViewer=new DaeViewer(pathToFile);
m_MainMdiArea->addSubWindow(QWidget::createWindowContainer(newViewer))->show();
```